# how do i add a number limit in an input field?

Tags: javascript, html

How can i have a number limit? im trying to make it so that you can only type the number 1-100 in "app-benutzer" and 1-15 in "backend-benutzer" also is there a way to display these numbers in the input field without typing them so it would show the user that you can only type the number from 1-15.

```
html:
 <body>
    App-Benutzer: <input type="number" min="1" max="100" class='appuser'></input><br>
    Backendbenutzer: <input type="number" min="1" max="15" class='backenduser'></input><br>
    <button class='calcit'>Berechnen</button><br>
    <span class='summe'>0.00</span><br>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
  </body>
js:
const btncalc = document.querySelector('.calcit');
const summetext = document.querySelector('.summe');


btncalc.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var backendanzahl= document.getElementsByClassName("backenduser")[0].value;

    var appanzahl= document.getElementsByClassName("appuser")[0].value;
    var mytext="Anzahl der Summe:" + (+backendanzahl * 35 + +appanzahl * 7.5) ;
    summetext.textContent = mytext;
});
```

Comment: @programmnoob Maybe you can add a hint text or a placeholder in the inputfield

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this only by using HTML.

This way, you can't really write anything more than what you specify in your terms.

**Clarification:**

`Placeholder` is the attribute that you use to put some text inside of your input field, but that text will disappear as soon as you click on your element.

`oninput` is the Event that occurs every time that `value` of your `input` element has changed. So basically, each time you write 1 number/letter/whatever, `oninput` event will trigger.

That's where we put our condition.

- `this.value` - represents what we write inside of our `input` element.

*our value (this.value)* = *if (this.value > 100)  (? represents something like return) return 100 ( (:) is like else) else return this.value*

`this.value = this.value > 100 ? 100 : Math.abs(this.value)`

is equivalent to

```
   if(this.value > 100) //this.value is what we write inside of the field
      return 100;
   else
      return this.value;
```

```html
 <body>
    App-Benutzer: <input type="number" min="1" max="100" oninput="this.value = this.value > 100 ? 100 : Math.abs(this.value)"  class='appuser' placeholder='1-100'></input><br>
    Backendbenutzer: <input type="number" min="1" max="15" oninput="this.value = this.value > 15 ? 15 : Math.abs(this.value)" class='backenduser' placeholder='1-15'></input><br>
    <button class='calcit'>Berechnen</button><br>
    <span class='summe'>0.00</span><br>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: this worked thank you still trying to understand the code but i will try

Comment: @programmnoob I will try to additionally explain in the answer

Comment: thank you very much that explains it very well

Answer (score 0):

You can use `placeholder` attribute of input field to put any text you want. This text will disapear once the user starts to edit the field. In you case you may may sat a placeholder to visualise "1-15".

```html
<body>
    App-Benutzer: <input type="number" min="1" max="100" class='appuser' placeholder="Input a value from 1 to 100"></input><br>
    Backendbenutzer: <input type="number" min="1" max="15" class='backenduser' placeholder="Input a value from 1 to 15"></input><br>
    <button class='calcit'>Berechnen</button><br>
    <span class='summe'>0.00</span><br>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
```